# How to use OpenLayers cluster strategies without using a Protocol

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

Using OpenLayers with Bing maps, I'm trying to load JSON data from a service URL and assign  an array of clustering strategies to the resulting layer. There are plenty of examples of using cluster strategies with **OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON** loaded via **OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP**, but my data is Plain Ol' JSON, not GeoJSON (and I have no control over the format of it).

So using this code, the points load on the map correctly. But I get an error:
**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'read' of null**". When I open up the OpenLayers source code to the error-causing line, it's this:

```
 layer.protocol.read(OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({
```

and indeed, **protocol** is null.

So my question is: How to use OpenLayers cluster strategies without using a Protocol?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("project-map");
osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({ name: 'street', type: 'Road', key : bingApiKey});
map.addLayer(osm);
var cp = new OpenLayers.LonLat(0,20).transform(fromProj, toProj);

var pointLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Markers",{
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), 
            new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({distance: 25})]
});

OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: "ServiceHandler.json", 
    success: function(response) {
      var jsonReader = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON();
      var sparkle = jsonReader.read(response.responseText);
        $.each(sparkle, function(i,f){
          var point = 
             new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(f.Long, f.Lat).transform(fromProj, toProj);
          var pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, null, 
        {
          externalGraphic: "http://localhost:8081/Icons/175.png",
          pointRadius: 8
        });
            pointFeature.attributes = f;
            pointLayer.addFeatures(pointFeature);
        });
        }
    });

    map.addLayer(pointLayer);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get error message by reason of using `Fixed` strategy. Remove this item from strategies array:

```
strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({distance: 25})]
```

It is not neccesary use `Fixed` strategy for manually added features.